# Why doesn't Postfix just bind to the IP I'm giving it?

Tags: networking, postfix, docker, ip

I genuinely believe this is a bug in Postfix, honestly.

Long story short, I have a server that runs multiple docker containers, each offering various services.

What I wanted was to use a single SMTP server running directly on the host OS that the containers could connect to and relay their emails through to the destination.

So, I decided to configure Postfix for this purpose.

In order for the docker containers to be able to reach my Postfix server, I went into main.cf and configured the following setting:

inet_interfaces = 127.0.0.1 172.16.0.255

172.16.0.255 is an IP running in the docker network, I believe, so it should be accessible to all containers.

Issue is, when starting the postfix server I get the following error:
fatal: parameter inet_interfaces: no local interface found for 172.16.0.255

Why?

I set the environment in such a way that doing "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_bind" results in "1", so I believe that it should work.

Moreover, when I do a lower IP like "172.17.0.1" it works for some reason. I would want to avoid doing this because after every single reboot, there's always a problem with postfix trying to bind to an IP that a docker container is already randomly bound to and so the binding fails for lower addresses. That's why I want an IP with a very high number like "172.16.0.255" so that docker won't interfere with its generated containers. But postfix refuses to bind to this address.

What can I do?

Comment: Notice that 172.17.0.1 is actually *64771 more* than 172.16.0.255. So, it's not a "lower ip". What is a network state of your system (at least, at the moment Postfix starts)? Why you choose a "dangerous" .255, why not try to use .254, for instance? Also, why do you want it to bind to non-local IP? Is this an attempt to build some kind of HA cluster? Then why it coexists with Docker?

Comment: You will usually get a very competent answer to such a question on the Postfix mailing list.

Comment: Using .254 is the same as .255. Docker should cover the entire 172.x.y.z range with the "{"base":"172.16.0.0/16","size":24}" configuration in daemon.json. I'm trying to bind to non-local IP because the docker services themselves will need to bind to reach my SMTP server somehow. Without this, postfix will refuse to relay emails from foreign addresses, I think

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that configuration? If you need to limit what interfaces Postfix is listening on, use `inet_interfaces` with an address actually visible to Postfix. If you are running Postfix behind NAT (really, don't..) and only forward certain connections anyway, why bother with what postfix binds to? Just leave it at `all`.

Comment: What I want is for Postfix to relay emails sent by docker containers. And to do that, from what I understand, I have to bind Postfix to a docker IP. My only issue is that, sometimes, when I bind with it the wrong IP, a docker container randomly takes that IP for itself before Postfix can bind to it and then Postfix cannot listen anymore to the network